# How to get depth between two spline raster layer in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have spline raster layers of same area and I need to know the distance between layers by every pixel.
I have prepared a sample drawing to define my problems.
[image: I have prepared a sample drawing to define my problems.]

Does anybody have an idea regarding my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to use map algebra. In ArcMap, if you have the spatial analyst extention, you can use the raster calculator. Just subtract the bottom layer from the top layer.

[image]

The resulting raster's values will represent the distance between the two surfaces in each pixel.

If you don't have access to Spatial Analyst extension, then consider using the open source software [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org)'s, it includes a [Raster Calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html) by default, that will perform what you are asking, and it's free!

[image]